# ApolloDriverのインポート

Tags: typescript

TypeScriptでApolloDriverをインポートするにはどうしたらいいんですか？

app.module.tsに以下の記述をしたいのですが、どうしてもApolloDriver だけ赤線でエラーになります。

```
import { GraphQLModule, ApolloDriver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
```

Comment: 赤線を出しているのはエディタや IDE でしょうか？カーソルを重ねると何か追加で情報が表示されたりしませんか？